# webhook realtime event on post shared to many facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

my application can share posts (like photos) to some user's page. (can be for multiple users).

when sharing a post, the user gives my app a permission for sharing. when doing this, my app receives token and post-id, and I can make API requests to get some post data like views etc...

I read [Webhooks api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/), but couldn't find any reference if my requested behaviour is supported: I could understand that the supported behaviour is the one if a user is manual configuring his page to support hooks.

to make better understanding, this is the flow:

1. some user is logged in to my app
2. user wants to share a photo from my app to his facebook page
3. user 'click' on share, accept the permissions, the photo is shared on his page, my app receive token and post id

I want to receive hooks to my app endpoint on any change to this post (like, view..)

is it possible??
thanks.

Comment: If the user shares to their own personal profile, then you can get updates if you subscribe for the user feed field. If they share on pages, then no, a page admin would have to give your app permission to subscribe to their feed updates first.

Comment: @CBroe can you point me to the documentation? most of my users are sharing to their facebook business page (not personal one). thanks!

Comment: Documentation for what?

Comment: "a page admin would have to give your app permission to subscribe to their feed updates first" can this done by showing permission on sharing? or only manual (going to admin page)

Comment: If you are posting to a page as the page, then you likely have the necessary permission `manage_pages` already ... otherwise, ask for it during login.

Comment: can you tell me which permission do i need to ask in order to get webhook from user business page posts?

Comment: You only need manage_pages to be able to subscribe to the page for updates.